# Better way to write if condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there any better way to write this condition?

```
if (self.expense.nil? && self.income.nil?) || (!self.expense.nil? && !self.income.nil?)
  puts "test"
end
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are testing to see if the expressions are both true or both false. Try this:

```
if (self.expense.nil? == self.income.nil?)
```

You don't care whether they are both true or both false, just that they are the same.

Comment: Holy crap, I didn't know that Ruby had a XOR operator. That's the last time I skip the boring syntax chapter! ;-)

Comment: @Tom Morris: Actually I think the xor isn't even necessary here. Check my update!

Comment: Yup. That's better in the context of the question. But I'm still grateful for learning about the XOR operator (^).

Answer (score 1):

Despite the logic, since you're using an if to check for nil you could shorten the code like so:

```
if ((expense && income) || (!expense && !income))
  puts "test"
end
```

Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: A problem that *might* occur (depending on the possible values for the variables) is if one of the variables is `false`. Then the original if-statment returns a different result than yours. But that only needs to be considered if `false` is a possible value for one of the used variables.

Comment: good point... though depending on the business logic, it may still work fine

Answer (score 0):

You could use Demorgan's law for the second half of the if condition

so `(!self.expense.nil? && !self.income.nil?)` becomes `!(self.expense.nil? || self.income.nil?)`